# What are the odds that some active personnel which may have a hand in processing my immigration-related applications may see my queries on this site?

Tags: uk

We have a number of quite knowledgable members here. I've always been curious for reasons of candid interest where many of their knowledgebases come from, but have rarely asked due to reluctance to be too intrusive or rude. One has disclosed that they had been an immigration officer in the past, but what are the odds that disclosures on TSE could influence, either consciously or unconsciously, the processing of one's immigration applications?

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have a way of estimating such odds, unless we could run a survey on immigration officials about their usage of this site. Therefore voting to close as opinion based. Perhaps you could rephrase it to something like "how do I avoid negatively influencing my case when asking a question about it online?"

Comment: I don't know. I wouldn't underestimate the types of things folks could draw on for objectively founded insights about things. Like, perhaps there are particular laws or procedures designed to prevent officers being influenced by things as jurors for a criminal trial in some places may be isolated from exposure to outside media? Or something else that neither of us are thinking of.

Comment: The first question would be, is the UK government able to match Stackexchange users with applicants with sufficient accuracy? And if they are, are immigration officials cleared for that kind of intelligence? I wonder how many "Joseph P." have an application pending right now ... explaining special cases would narrow it down, but would that be exact enough to base a decision on it?

Comment: You can change your username here, though not very often.

Comment: If anything, the fact that this site's contents show up on Google are likely to be more relevant than anybody's direct use of the site.

Comment: I asked a friend of mine who works quite high level in the Home Office - her response was that yes, UK immigration does consider this and other immigration orientated sites a source of information or intelligence they are interested in, and regularly harvests them.  What they do with the information afterward she couldnt say (didnt know), but it seems likely something is done with the information.

Comment: @Joseph P. If you feel any concern about this possibility, the best approach would be not to post a question(s) at all

Comment: @o.m. There probably aren’t many ‘Joseph P’ who are US citizens and on immigration bail after overstaying for around 3 years, having previously been refused entry and subsequently entered via Ireland. Maybe not exact enough to base a decision on alone, but sufficient to provoke further enquiries eg through highlighting potential discrepancies in information given, and potentially lead to a request from Immigration authorities for TSE to disclose user information under the relevant law for civil, administrative, criminal, and national security purposes.

Comment: @Traveller, this Joseph P (if that is his real name) certainly has given enough specifics to narrow it down. Regarding information requests, I believe SE is an American company, and they write that they will comply with all valid requests -- does that count UK requests, or would that have to go through an American court?

Comment: Quora has few (usually retired) officers that answers some questions, but nobody want to make the job of the peers more difficult. And to quote a UK TV show (from an immigration officers: "people think they can lie, but they are very bad liars"). [and it seems they have much more data, just they do not use resources to chase people for minor things] Not being honest gives them suspicious that you are hiding very very bad stuffs. Warning: you should not pass the line of criminal charges

Comment: They look at the "visas" section of the UK-Yankees forum site. I know that for a fact.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey How do you know that for such a fact?

Comment: I just do. All kinds of immigration professionals read those sites. Lawyers, judges, enforcement, charity workers, policy makers.

Comment: But I meant that specific site.

Comment: Why would I tell you how I know that?

Comment: I will say that organisations trawl through social media, web forums, blogs, etc, to find out all kinds of things, not just hints of planned wrongdoing or circumventions, but to find out what people think of them in all sorts of ways - the quality of their facilities, their documentation, timely service, rude staff, the user experience in general, plus what their own staff might be posting.